# Do you need permission to show an RSS feed?

Tags: rss

Does anyone know if you need permission to show an RSS feed on your website? I want to show the BBC business RSS feed and I heard that I may need to get permission to show it. I did some Googling but couldn't find anything so does anyone know if this is true and if it is, how do I get permission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To display content from another site, you need permission.  Most sites that have RSS feeds do give this permission.  RSS feeds are designed to share content, often for syndication.  Permission is usually readily available for republishing RSS feeds.

The BBC does give such permission for republishing their RSS feeds.  Here are the [Terms and Conditions for the use of BBC RSS feeds](http://www.bbc.co.uk/terms/additional_rss.shtml)

> 2.3   You may use the BBC RSS Feed in order to display the BBC Content on your website, blog or other product or service.

So yes, you can show the RSS feed on your website.  There are some limitations and requirements (modifications, use of the logo, notification to your users about the TOC), so read and follow the rest of the terms and conditions.